# calculation of enthalpy change

Tags: energy, enthalpy, heat

So for for the calculation of $\Delta{H}$,we have two formulaes in our book:

$\Delta{H}=E_{2}-E_{1}$
where $E_{2},E_{1}$ are the internal energies of the product and reactants respectively.
Now this makes sense to me,But we've another formula for calculating $\Delta{H}$ which is

$\Delta{H}=B_{1}-B_{2}$
Here $B_1$ is the total bond energy of the reactant and $B_2$ is the total bond energy of the products

I don't understand where this formula comes from,in this formula we are not taking into account the individual energies of the atoms.Dont they differ according to their orientation?And the orientation of them becomes different when they react to become products.

Here are my questions

1.So does this formula really gives a close approximation of $\Delta{H}$?

2.And,where does this formula comes from?

Comment: Both formulas are wrong, as enthalpy is not the same as internal energy and the difference in the bond energies is not the same as the enthalpy change.

Comment: so what are those formulas for exactly?

Comment: Please cite the source of the these equations and provide more context. It is really hard to just have an equation without the actual definitions of the variables within. And for your own benefit, you might want to consider not starting sentences with 'so', and pay more attention to spelling and punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About the equation $ΔH = E_2 - E_1$:**

Note that by definition: $ΔH = ΔU + Δ(pV) =  E_2 - E_1 + Δ(pV) $

For an ideal gas: $ΔH = E_2 - E_1 + Δn \cdot RT$, with the last term being typically about $\pu{2.2 kJ mol-1}$ with total amount change by $\pu{1 mol}$.

For isobaric changes in condensed phases, the term $Δ(pV)$ is often negligible.
For isochoric changes in condensed phases, the term $Δ(pV)$ can be enormous due big changes of pressure due very limited compressibility.

**About the equation $ΔH = B_2 - B_1$:**

Note that $ΔH = ΔU + Δ(pV) = ΔU_\text{bond} + ΔU_\text{kin, transl} + ΔU_\text{kin, vibr} + ΔU_\text{kin, rot} \\
+ ΔU_\text{pot, vibr} + ΔU_\text{pot, other} + ΔU_\text{electronic} + ... + Δ(pV)$

| U form | U legend |
| --- | --- |
| $U_\text{bond}$ | potential energy of bonds(negative) |
| $U_\text{kin, transl}$ | translational part of thermal kinetic energy |
| $U_\text{kin, vibr}$ | vibrational part of thermal kinetic energy |
| $U_\text{kin, rot}$ | rotational part of thermal kinetic energy |
| $U_\text{pot, vibr}$ | vibrational part of thermal potential energy |
| $U_\text{pot, other}$ | collision part of thermal potential energy |
| $U_\text{electronic}$ | electron excitation part of thermal potential energy |